# How to avoid using callbacks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There's this callback thing in Rails that has been bugging me for a while. The thing is, I don't like them. Mainly because they slow my tests down, since I have to hit the database in my unit tests in order to persist the object, which trigger the callbacks (after_save, for example).

I'm going to use a simple example of what I want to do to make myself clearer. Suppose I have an account, and every time I make a withdraw, I have to deduct the amount from the balance. My models are:

```
class Withdraw < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  after_save :update_account_balance

  private
    def update_account_balance
      self.account.balance -= self.amount
      self.account.save
    end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :withdraws
end
```

So, if I were to test that behavior, what I would have to do is (using RSpec):

```
describe Withdraw

  it 'updates the account balance' do
    account = Account.create({ :name => "foo", :balance => 100 })
    withdraw.create({ :amount => 10, :account => account })
    account.balance.should == 90
  end
end
```

Notice that I had to hit the database twice in that unit test. That would be OK in a simple project, but it starts to become a liability when the test suite grows (500 examples or so).

I could make the `update_account_balance` method public and call it from the controller, but I think that's business logic and doesn't belong in controller code.

I've tried googling for a solution but couldn't find one. How do you guys with fast tests suites address this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to skip callbacks, you can use something like `my_model.save(false)`.  By the way, you should save account after updating its balance.

Comment: I mean you should update account's balance like `set balance=balance-amount`.

Comment: @taro This is just an example I made up to explain my point, not code that's actually running, but I added the `self.account.save` so my example is semantically correct. Now, I _really_ don't see how skipping callbacks would help here.

Comment: Imo the model is sketchy anyway, it'd make more sense to ask the account to withdraw an amount, the math can be done there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have made the action of doing a `withdrawal` implicit (namely it occurs by virtue of a `Withdraw` object being created)

I think there's a better way to do it.

```
account.withdraw!(1000)
```

Code may look like this.

```
class Account

  def withdraw!(amount)
    transaction do
      withdrawal = self.withdrawals.build(:amount => amount)

      self.subtract_balance(amount)

      withdrawal.save!
    end
  end

  private

  def subtract_balance(amount)
    connection.execute(
      "UPDATE #{self.class.table_name} SET balance = balance - #{amount} WHERE id = #{self.id}"
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: That does help making my intentions more explicit, but it's still persisting the object in order to update the account balance, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: well, don't you need a receipt of some sort to store this? if you don't then just skip the lines that build the object. But in any real business, you need to account for these things.

Comment: also, I don't think you should be making coding decisions based on how slow it makes your tests.

Comment: Oh but I do. If my tests are driving my code, I should make coding decisions based on testability. If my tests are not efficient, neither is my code. My (limited) experience shown it leads to more maintainable code. Take this example. If I wasn't worried about my tests, I would have ended up using callbacks, which IMO are bad - they hide your intentions and are hard to debug.